# Integer array iteration in java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I iterate through a specific range in an array and perform validation or operation using java 8 streams

Eg:

```
for(int i= startIndex; i< endIndex;i++) {
    total+=arr[i];
}
```

or

```
boolean emptyArray = true;
for(int i= startIndex; i< endIndex;i++) {
   if(array[i] != 0) {
       emptyArray = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Deadpool OP is looking for Java 8 Stream version of the shown code.

Comment: yes...that is what I wanted......I tried `IntStream.range` but didn't work

Comment: @Deadpool Both are processing **part** of the array. Did you read the one sentence in the question at all? *"How can I iterate through a **specific range** in an array and perform validation or operation **using java 8 streams**"*

Comment: In this specific case, calculating `total` which is `> 0` can be used to derive that the array is not empty. So a single iteration should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `skip()` and `limit()` of `Stream`:

```
Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
List<Integer> slice = s.skip(1).limit(2)
      .collect(Collectors.toList()));
System.out.println(slice); // prints [2, 3]
```

To translate your first example:

```
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int startIndex = 1;
int endIndex = 3;
int total = Arrays.stream(array)
        .skip(startIndex)
        .limit(endIndex - startIndex /*assuming endIndex is always > startIndex */)
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .sum();
System.out.println(total); // prints 5
```

Comment: Up-voted, but for a better answer, you should include the stream version of the two snippets of code in the question, i.e. the first one using `sum()` and the second using one of the `xxxMatch()` methods.

Comment: Is This Java8 code...looks like java11 to me

Comment: @user3310115 You referring to the `var` that was added in Java 10?

Comment: @user3310115 yes, but I edited to show the actual types - but it should not matter for the question as the answer is about showing `skip` and `limit` usage.

Comment: @Stuck - I was looking for a specific range. Is that possible? In my question, I have the exact `startIndex` and `endIndex` with em

Comment: I added a translation of you first example to the stream api.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] arr = new int[] {15, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9, 10};
int startIndex = 1;
int endIndex = 4;
int sum = Arrays.stream(arr, startIndex, endIndex)
         .sum();
System.out.println(sum);
```

output:

```
6
```

startIndex is inclusive, and endIndex is exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `IntStream.range(startInclusive, endExclusive)` to iterate an array:

```
 int arr[] = new int[] { 1, 2, 0, 5, 6, 7};

 int sum = IntStream.range(0, 3).map(i -> arr[i]).sum();

 boolean emptyArray = !IntStream.range(0, 3).anyMatch(i -> arr[i] != 0);
 System.out.println(emptyArray);
 emptyArray = IntStream.range(2, 2).allMatch(i -> arr[i] == 0);
 System.out.println(emptyArray);
```

`anyMatch(predicate)` searches for the first item matching the `predicate` and `allMatch(predicate)` returns `true` if all items match the `predicate`.